# ListView set contents gravity to right

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a Fragment in which there is a ListView.
The ListView is populated using a simple ArrayAdapter which its code is below.
I want the ListView to show it's content from RIGHT to LEFT.
(I want each row of ListView to set its text to its right)
The gravity set to right seems to do nothing.

I tried a couple of solutions suggested in here but I don't know why no matter what change I make I don't see any difference.

I have changed width of `ListView` and `Layouts` to `match_parent`, `fill_parent`, `wrap_content`... nothing changed.

**My Activity xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com..SearchResultListActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

**My Fragment xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.***.SearchResultListActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSearchResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Activity Class:**

```
public class SearchResultListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
    //ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    //DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result_list);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_result_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            String[] array = new String[] {"cat", "dog", "mouse"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
            ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result_list, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tina, see my answer with the correct way to create a custom layout for your `ListView`.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite catch you here. What do u mean by correct way? I did everything u told me to do. I left comments under your answer.

Comment: Tina, by correct way I mean create a custom layout to represent your list item and a custom adapter to inflate this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the android list item layout, that's why you are not seeing the content correctly, also because you have changed the gravity of the `ListView` itself, not its content. You should set the gravity of the items, and they must be declared in a new layout file with a custom adapter.

First of all remove the `android:layout_gravity="right"` from your **Fragment xml** layout, it won't be needed anymore.

Also your `ListView` width must be set to `match_parent`.

#### Change your Fragment.xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.***.SearchResultListActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSearchResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you must create a new layout to represent the items of your `ListView`.

#### 1. Create a list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_row"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, we set the `layout_gravity` of the item in this layout, this way the content of your `Listview` will have this behavior, to be in the right of the `ListView`.

#### 2. Create custom array adapter class as inner class

Also you must create a custom Adapter to inflate the layout and set the values correctly. This is how your Activity should look with the custom array adapter as inner class

```
public class SearchResultListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
    //ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    //DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result_list);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_result_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            String[] array = new String[] {"cat", "dog", "mouse"};

            // Here we initialize the custom array adapter sending the proper values to the constructor
            MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, array);
            ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);

            // Here we set the custom adapter to the Listview
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result_list, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    // This is the custom adapter class where you will manage the behavior of your ListView content
    public class MyArrayAdapter extends MyArrayAdapter<String>{

        Context context; 
        int layoutResourceId; // This is the layout you created for the list items   
        String data[] = null; // the array with the data to populate the listview

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;

                            // Here we inflate the list item layout to load its views (the TextView)
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();    
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            // Now we can get the TextView from the layout
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            // Here we set the value from a specific position in the array
            txtTitle.setText(data[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }

}
```

#### 3. Initialize your adapter

Now you must initialize your adapter based on the custom adapter you created before, like this.

```
MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, array);
```

As you can see here we send the custom `list_item.xml` layout and the array with the data you want to populate also the context on the constructor.

#### 4. Set the adapter to your listview

Now you must set the adapter you created before to your `ListView`

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Let me know if you have more doubts.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I just added android:gravity="right" to my list_item layout. It's right to left!! Yeay! Thanks man. Please add this tiny edit to your answer for future visitors. I already accepted yours.

Comment: Thanks again man. I highly appreciate your thorough answer. You really saved some ... here :)

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the gravity of the `ListView` container but not the rows it contains as I assume you wanted to.

It's a little unclear whether you want right aligned text or text that gets populted from the right to the left. Either way the solution is the same.

The best solution would be to copy the code from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` into your own layout and change the properties of the `TextView` in there. (Ensure that you keep the View's id the same unless you want to change more of your Adapter code.)
You can find the built-in layouts at `<android-sdk-root>/platforms/<version>/data/res/layout/`.

Then load your adapter with:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                   getActivity(),
                                   R.layout.my_simple_list_item,   // use your layout
                                   array);
```

The v19 simple_list_item_1 for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```